# Diferença entre o + dentro e fora de parênteses em DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

Recentemente, eu estava desenvolvendo um *DTD* para validar um dado *XML*, e queria saber se há alguma diferença entre estas duas expressões:

```
 <!ELEMENT examples (example+)> ("+" dentro dos parênteses)
```

e

```
<!ELEMENT examples (example)+> ("+" fora dos parênteses)
```